# How to get the intersection of high dimensional convex hulls in Matlab?

Tags: geometry, matlab

I have two $10$-dimensional convex hulls from using the Matlab function 'Convhulln'.

I would like to know to what extent they overlap. In a $2D$ scenario the 'intersect' function can be used but not in higher dimensions.

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Preferably I would like to know by how many percent the hulls overlap.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you have a lot of points per hull, and a way to calculate the volume of a single hull, you can get a rough lower bound by finding the points of each hull that are inside the other, and taking the convex hull of those. Otherwise, I would look through the [Matlab file exchange] (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)

Comment: You can also use the method of random points ("shooting $10^{6} $ rand(1,10) points)") : the ratio of volumes $V(A)/V(B)$ is roughly the ratio $\#(A)/\#(B)$ of the number of random points having fallen in $A$, resp. $B$.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution! Do you know how I can test whether an individual point is in the hull?

Comment: A first answer (but with a long execution time) : Let $convhull(...)$ be the convex hull operator ; let $K=convhull(P_1,\cdots P_n)$ ;  a point $M$ is interior to $K$ if $convhull(\{M\} \cup K)=K$.

Comment: Sorry but I am a total amateur when it comes to mathematical notation. How would this look in Matlab code?